Variational AutoEncoder using a matrix as dataset with a time component or ...?
The project is to repair data/smoothing.
I would like to use a matrix of shape (5,13,3922):

5 differents types
13 features, one of them is the Times series, dates in format
yyyy-mm-dd that I turned in to_numerics so they are floats
3922 the number of datapoints

I would like to use this because the 5 type are correlated and it would make easier to have a model that can be trained on all 5 instead of having 1 for each. And dataframe can't handle multidimensionality.
Can we incorporate the Time parameter differently ? Should I stick to (5,12,3922) without a time component ?
If you have any material related, I'd be glad if you can share.
Many thanks !
